# ngx-bootstrap: Sortable with template (horizontally)

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I'm currently having an issue using the ngx-bootstrap sortable component.

I want to be able to use the sortable component horizontally instead of the stacked vertical examples from the doc examples. [ngx-bootstrap sortable](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable)

Would anyone be able to help out here by providing a potential solution or be able to explain why this may not be possible using ngx-bootstrap.

Comment: you still need drag and drop functionality, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bs-sortable` creates `div`s internally to show the draggable elements. Now by default the `display` property of `div` is `block`, thats why it is arranged in vertical stack.

To make it horizontal you just need to add the css property `display` to `inline-block` in class `sortable-item`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdhqaz)

**Template**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <bs-sortable
      [(ngModel)]="itemStringsLeft"
      itemClass="sortable-item"
      itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
      placeholderItem="Drag here"
      placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
      wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
    ></bs-sortable>
    <pre class="code-preview">model: {{ itemStringsLeft | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <bs-sortable
      [(ngModel)]="itemStringsRight"
      itemClass="sortable-item"
      itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
      placeholderItem="Drag here"
      placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
      wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
    ></bs-sortable>
    <pre class="code-preview">model: {{ itemStringsRight | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```css
.sortable-item {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #adadad;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Rather than making changes in global `style.css` (which will apply changes globally), if you want to make changes in particular component only, you can use `ng-deep` pseudo selector in particular component.

**app.component.css**

```css
bs-sortable::ng-deep .sortable-item {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #adadad;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does work however I'm having trouble overriding the user agent styling that this comes with. For some reason it doesn't allow me to override that display:block style with inline?

Comment: Have you checked my stackblitz demo? you need to put styles in global styles.css to make it work. inline styles wont work here as it is input property.

Comment: @MylesJeremiah I have edited with new update. Please have a look.